# What are values of $2^i, i^i$ and $(-1)^{2i}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is the value of $2^i$ $\cos(\ln(2)) + i\;\sin(\ln(2))$? But I don't know how to calculate the value of $i^i$? And for the last one, is it the same as $1^i$? Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Since $i=e^{i \frac{\pi}2 }$, we have $i^i = {\left(e^{i \frac \pi 2} \right)}^i = \dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the value of $2^i$, note that $x = 2^i \implies \ln x = i \ln 2$, so $x = e^{i \ln 2} = i\sin (\ln 2) + \cos (\ln 2)$.

For the value of $i^i$, note that $i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$, so $i^i$ is any one of the values $e^\frac{-(2n+1)\pi}{2}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For the value of $(-1)^{2i}$, note that $-1 = e^{-i(2n+1)\pi}$, so $(-1)^{2i} = e^{-2(2n+1)\pi}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You have a typo in your second line, the index should be something like $\frac{i \cdot i (2n+1) \pi}2$

Comment: @GFauxPas Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Isn't it the same? Since $i^2=-1$?

Comment: @J.doe You have noticed the post after the edit. Before the edit there was an $i$ rather than a $-$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @J.doe You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Definition...
$$
a^b = \exp(b\log a)
$$
Of course "$\log$" is the natural logarithm.
And it is multi-valued.  Suppose we choose "principal values" as
$$
\log(-1) = i\pi,
\\
\log i = \frac{i\pi}{2}
$$
then what do we get?  Can you compute the values for $i^i$ and $(-1)^{2i}$ yourself?

And what happens if you choose some value other than these principal values?

Answer (score 2):

$e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$

$2 = e^{\ln2}$

$2^i = e^{i\ln2} = \cos (\ln 2) + i \sin (\ln 2)$

$i = e^{\frac \pi2 i}, i^i = e^{-\frac \pi2}$

$-1 = e^{ \pi i}, (-1)^{2i} = e^{-2\pi}$